# Multiplication result in batch is a negative value?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

**I am running this batch program,**

```
@echo off
cls
set /a answer=2*1073741824
echo %answer%
pause>nul
```

**Output am getting,**

```
-2147483648
```

**Expected Output,**

```
2147483648
```

*The problem I am facing is the output returns in a negative value, and I don't know what's wrong. What solutions exist to help me resolve this problem using batch?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Calculate large integers in batch with a PowerShell helper

## 1. Batch

> **Essentially you can . . .**
>
> 1. Set a mathematical equation as a string variable in your batch script such as  `SET "Calculation=2*1073741824"`
> 2. Set the `MathType` string variable value for the operator type i.e. `*`.
> 3. Use the **#1** and **#2** batch variables and plug those into small PowerShell commands to create a dynamic script with the batch `ECHO` command.
> 4. The PowerShell logic will [split](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) apart each numerical portion of the **#1** value and delimit it by the math operator (*e.g. `*`*) so each can be reused individually to do the large number calculation in PowerShell.
>
> **Finally**, run the execution of the script through a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and save that executed result as a batch variable. This allows PowerShell to do the large `int` arithmetic calculation where it can handle more bytes, but also allows the result to be later used as a string variable in batch.

---

#### Batch Script

```
SET "Calculation=3*1073741824"
SET "MathType=*"

SET PSScript=%temp%\PS~MathTemp.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Calculation = "%Calculation%"                                             > "%PSScript%"
ECHO [int]$Calculation.split("%MathType%")[0] %MathType% [int]$Calculation.split("%MathType%")[1] >> "%PSScript%"

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"') DO SET "nCalc=%%I"

ECHO %nCalc%
PAUSE
```

---

## 2. PowerShell

> **As suggested by others**, I made a simple PowerShell script that will do this by passing it two arguments with those being...
>
> 1. Simple two number calculation as an entire string (e.g. "`4 + 4`", "`823*7`", "`8  /2`", ..., etc.)
> 2. The [arithmetic operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6)
>      of `*`, `/`, `+`, or `-` which should always match the #1 two number
>      calculation arithmetic operator used in the same execution

#### PowerShell Script

```
$Calculation = $args[0];
$MathType    = $args[1];
$p1  = [int]$Calculation.split($MathType)[0].Trim();
$p2  = [int]$Calculation.split($MathType)[1].Trim();
$cmd = "$p1 $MathType $p2";
Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd
```

#### Execution Example

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> & "C:\Scripts\PassCalc.ps1" "9 /  5 " "/"
1.8
```

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [PowerShell Data Types](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [Invoke-Expression](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html)

Comment: Perhaps this can handle more than the "simple" calculation as I stated in the PowerShell section—I kept my testing simple and thus my answer detail as well.

Answer (score 1):

If things fail working in the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Batch File Preprocessor*, you can always use the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Powershell* Integrated Shell-Scripting Environment or the *Cygwin* Environment.

In the latter, you can use the `bc` Software Utility. It can perform advanced calculations. You can mix it with a Shell-Scripting Environment such as the *Bourne-Again* Shell-Scripting Environment and get the results that you want.

```
dobre@Laptop ~
$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
2*1073741824
2147483648


dobre@Laptop ~
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hidden ****`-`****  in your variable **`%answer:-=%`**:

---

```bat
@echo off & cls 
set /a answer=2*1073741824
echo=%answer:-=% & pause>nul

rem :: you can remove from variable by :: 
set "answer=%answer:-=%"
echo=%answer%
```

---