# Complex escape coding in a batch for-loop

Tags: batch, escape-characters

Reference is made to https://superuser.com/a/1508668/1884857

In my code I have added [Vomit IT's](https://superuser.com/users/510662/vomit-it-chunky-mess-style) code into a for loop. However, the code stops at the line:

```bash
ECHO [int]$Calculation.split("%MathType%")[0] %MathType% [int]$Calculation.split("%MathType%")[1] >> "%PSScript%"
```

> The error output from running the batch is:
> *[0] was unexpected at this time.*

My question is therefore how to make the code function in a for loop (e.g. looping through files in a folder)?

I have tried various escape methods, e.g.

```
ECHO [int]$Calculation.split("!MathType!")[0] !MathType! [int]$Calculation.split("!MathType!")[1] >> "!PSScript!"
```

Sadly, still with no luck.

Would be grateful for any ideas.

This is the original code from the other post:

```bash
SET "Calculation=3*1073741824"
SET "MathType=*"
    
SET PSScript=%temp%\PS~MathTemp.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Calculation = "%Calculation%" > "%PSScript%"
ECHO [int]$Calculation.split("%MathType%")[0] %MathType% [int]$Calculation.split("%MathType%")[1] >> "%PSScript%"
    
For /F "Delims=" %%I IN (`Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"`) Do Set "nCalc=%%I"
```

Edit: @io-io solved it! For completeness, here is my entire script. It scans all video files in a file list and processes them with ffmpeg.

````
REM Change the console encoding to UTF-8 (for Nordic characters).
chcp 65001 | echo/

set filelist=%1
echo %filelist%

REM Define ESC escape character
for /f %%d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%%d")

REM Loop through all video files lists in a separate filelist
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%filelist%") do (
    call :StartTimer
    set Bytes=%%~za

    REM Below timestamp coding depends on locale setting on computer
    set Timestamp=%%~ta
    set TSYYYY=!Timestamp:~6,4!
    set TSYY=!Timestamp:~8,2!
    set TSMM=!Timestamp:~3,2!
    set TSDD=!Timestamp:~0,2!
    set TSHR=!Timestamp:~11,2!
    set TSMIN=!Timestamp:~14,2!
    set TSDato=!TSYY!!TSMM!!TSDD!
    set TSTid=!TSHR!!TSMIN!
    
    REM Display information about input file
    echo !ESC![92;103mInputfile="%%~fa"!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![92;103mInputfile size=!Bytes! Bytes!ESC![0m

    REM Convert to MP4 if needed, and compress to iPhone supported HEVC format
    echo !ESC![91mConvert %%~xa file to MP4 format, and compress to iPhone supported HEVC format!ESC![0m
    ffmpeg -n -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -i "%%~fa" -vcodec libx265 -vsync 0 -vtag hvc1 -crf 28 "%%~dpna_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4"
    REM Reset Console command after running ffmpeg
    chcp 65001 | echo/

    REM Find size of new file
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%b IN ("%%~dpna_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4") DO set OutBytes=%%~zb
    
    **REM Find compression ratio new vs old file
    SET "Calculation=!OutBytes!/!Bytes!"
    SET "MathType=/"
    SET PSScript=%temp%\PS~MathTemp.ps1
    IF EXIST "!PSScript!" DEL /Q /F "!PSScript!"
    ECHO $Calculation = "!Calculation!" > "!PSScript!"
    ECHO [int]$Calculation.split("!MathType!"^)[0] !MathType! [int]$Calculation.split("!MathType!"^)[1] >> "!PSScript!"
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%c IN (`Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '!PSScript!'"`) DO SET "Compression=%%c"**
    
    REM Display compression summary
    echo !ESC![42mSummary!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![32mInputfile="%%~fa"!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![32mInputfile size=!Bytes! Bytes!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![32mOutputfile="%%~dpna_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4"!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![32mOutputfile size=!OutBytes! Bytes!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![32mCompression rate=!Compression!!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![42mFile "%%~a" optimisation complete!ESC![0m

    REM Clean up. If new file created, delete original file
    if NOT exist "%%~dpna_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4" (
        echo !ESC![33mNo optimization has been performed!ESC![0m
    ) else (
        del "%%~fa"
        echo !ESC![47;91mOriginal file has been DELETED!ESC![0m
    )
    call :StopTimer
    call :DisplayTimerResult
    REM pause >nul
);=

echo. & echo All files optimised! & endlocal

REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313897/timer-in-windows-batch-file
:StartTimer
:: Store start time
set StartTIME=%TIME%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %StartTIME: =0%`) do set /a Start100S=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i-36610100
goto :EOF

:StopTimer
:: Get the end time
set StopTIME=%TIME%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %StopTIME: =0%`) do set /a Stop100S=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i-36610100
:: Test midnight rollover. If so, add 1 day=8640000 1/100ths secs
if %Stop100S% LSS %Start100S% set /a Stop100S+=8640000
set /a TookTime=%Stop100S%-%Start100S%
set TookTimePadded=0%TookTime%
goto :EOF

:DisplayTimerResult
:: Show timer start/stop/delta
echo Started: %StartTime%
echo Stopped: %StopTime%
echo Elapsed: %TookTime:~0,-2%.%TookTimePadded:~-2% seconds
goto :EOF```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a non-working code snippet (with noticed `for` loop). Hard to guess…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
@echo off

set "_Math=*"
set "_Calc=3*1073741824"    
set "_PSSctr=%tmp%\PS~MathTemp.ps1"

2>nul del /q /f "%_PSSctr%"

> "%_PSSctr%" (
     echo/$Calc = "%_Calc%"
     echo/[int]$Calc.split("%_Math%"^)[0] %_Math% [int]$Calc.split("%_Math%"^)[1]
    )
    
For /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%i in (`
     Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%_PSSctr%'"
    `) do set "_nCalc=%%~i"

echo/%_nCalc%
```

---

**1.** You made changes to the original code, changing `" ' "` to `` " ` " `` in the execution of the original `For /F` loop changed `(' ... ')` to `` (` ... `) ``

**2.** The escapes you need are in `echo ...` where it contains the closing `)`, and only in the closing of `^)`, besides, if you are going to use `` ` ``, so add `Usebackq` in your `For /f` loop

Comment: Just perfect! Solved my question! Had to replace some % around parameters with !, but I would NEVER have figured out the issue with the two different types of apostrophes by myself. Same goes for the use of escape character only for the ending bracket. Amazing. Huge thanks, io-io!

Comment: Thank you also for testing, commenting and for the other relevant actions!